# Unreliable count of messages pushed to Service Bus using Durable Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-core-3.1, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-durable-functions

I'm getting this weird issue when using Durable Azure functions to submit messages to azure service bus.

My code is a simple Fan-Out implementation

- REST trigger get the number of messages to be submitted and hands that an orchestrator.
- Orchestrator stores the calls activity which will create and submit the message to Service bus.

The issue is when I send the REST parameter asking to add 3000 messages, more than 3000 get added.

Worse, it's not the same number either - 3104, 3100, 3286 anything...

[image]

[image]

See code below:

```
[FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
//public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
public static async Task<IActionResult> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    String type = req.Query["type"];
    if(!long.TryParse(req.Query["count"], out var count))
    {
        return new ObjectResult($"Parse failed for parameter 'count' ({req.Query["count"]}) to Int.") { StatusCode = 400};
    }

    var restInputs = new RestInputs() 
        { Type = type, Count = count };

    // Function input comes from the request content.
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync
        ("EmailQueueSubmitter_OrchestratorSingleton"
        , restInputs);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}

[FunctionName("EmailQueueSubmitter_OrchestratorSingleton")]
public static async Task<List<string>> EmailQueueSubmitter_OrchestratorSingleton(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        var restInputs = context.GetInput<RestInputs>();

        var parallelTasks = new List<Task>();
        long runBatchLen;
        long i_batch, i_iter, batchCount = 0;

        for (i_batch = 0; i_batch < restInputs.Count; i_batch++)
        {
            parallelTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync("EmailQueueSubmitter_ActivitySendMessageBatchSingleton", i_batch.ToString()));
            log.LogWarning($"Message {i_batch} Added");
        }

        log.LogWarning($"Awaiting {parallelTasks.Count} tasks");
        await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
        var doneTaskCount = parallelTasks.Where(t => t.IsCompleted).ToList().Count;
        var successTaskCount = parallelTasks.Where(t => t.IsCompletedSuccessfully).ToList().Count;
        var faultedTaskCount = parallelTasks.Where(t => t.IsFaulted).ToList().Count;
        var exceptionTaskCount = parallelTasks.Where(t => t.Exception != null).ToList().Count;
        log.LogWarning($"Done:{doneTaskCount}, Success: {successTaskCount}, Fault:{faultedTaskCount}, Exception:{exceptionTaskCount}");

        log.LogWarning($"Achieved completion.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
    }

    return outputs;
}
[FunctionName("EmailQueueSubmitter_ActivitySendMessageBatchSingleton")]
public static async Task EmailQueueSubmitter_ActivitySendMessageBatchSingleton([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext activityContext, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogWarning($"Starting Activity.");
    var payload = activityContext.GetInput<String>();
    
    await ServiceBus_Sender.SendMessageBatch(payload);
    log.LogWarning($"Finished Activity.");
}
public static ServiceBusMessage CreateMessage(String Payload)
{
    try
    {
        var sbMsg = new ServiceBusMessage(Payload)
        {
            MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            ContentType = "text/plain"
        };
        //sbMsg.ApplicationProperties.Add("RequestType", "Publish");

        return sbMsg;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#internal-queue-triggers -> "Orchestrator, entity, and activity functions are all triggered by internal queues in the function app's task hub. Using queues in this way provides reliable **"at-least-once"** message delivery guarantees." -> emphasis mine. It's entirely on you to determine if a message was duplicated or not.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : thanks for the comment: but how can we run a duplicates check in Service bus? My code up top is a dummy, in reality the messages will be constructed from DB records and must be pushed to the SB. The production scenario could have up to 1M records to send out at a time.

Comment: You need some sort of ID. You could generate a Guid and send it together with the data, and then check that the Guid wasn't handled already before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Camilo Terevinto for the information, I am converting this to an answer so that may help other community members:

As suggested in the comments, to run a duplicate check   you could generate a **Guid** and send it together with the data, and then check that the **Guid** wasn't handled already before. Hopefully this resolved your issue.

***OP Edit:*** Duplicates check was enabled by changing the service bus queue to be session enabled and have de-duplication turned on. The submitted messages' MessageId was set to be unique in each session. This is the only way I can think of to deal with the *at-least-once* guarantees...